# .htaccess Seemingly Ignoring select Rewrite Rules, But Not All

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Background:**

1. Running Apache 2.4 on Centos7
2. My rewrite and redirect rules are in a .htaccess file in the website root directory
3. Right now Multiviews is set to +, but have tried both + and -.

**What I am trying to do:**

I would like to do something as [explained here](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) which removes file extensions and replaces them with a trailing slash in the URL of the browser. In this case .php and .html.

But when I enter the code below, I do not get the desired result.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

RewriteEngine On is set already, and this is not the first thing on my .htacess - should it be? Here is the top of my root directory level .htaccess file. I do have Multiviews and other things like Indexes set at the configuration level (httpd.conf).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirects all www to non www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect index.php and index.html to / via https://www.smartlabsoftware.com/howto/redirect-index-page.htm
   #
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.(html|php)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html|php)?$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#this code does not work and breaks rewrite rules below it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
##
```

**The problems** I am encountering if I include the block of code that I listed first:

- something with mulitviews where the index.php to / rewrite no longer
  works.
- no trailing slash added
- the .php extension never goes away
- other rewrite  rules further down in my file stop working.

**What I need to happen:**

.php or .html to be removed and for a trailing slash to be added. For example:

- mywebsite.com/contact/staff.php, if requested should load as mywebsite.com/contact/staff/
- mywebsite.com/contact/staff, if requested should load as mywebsite.com/contact/staff/
- mywebsite.com/contact/index.php, if requested, should load mywebsite.com/contact/
- For rewrite rules to work, for example

```
        RewriteRule   ^elderlaw/?$              radio/minute-type.php?id=3 [R=301,NC,L]
```

**Additional problem**

Even if I do not attempt to add the code block above, my RewriteRules only work if I do not include the flags in the [] brackets. So my RewriteRule actually looks like this

```
        RewriteRule   ^elderlaw/?$              radio/minute-type.php?id=3
```

If I include the flags, it simply redirects to my webpage instead of rewriting the URL.

Yes I am restarting apache each time, yes I am clearing browser cache each time while testing. I have mod_rewrite enabled and my RewriteEngine is on.

Any ideas? I have tried so many things.

Comment: MultiViews _and_ rewriting are usually not good to be used together, that always leads to trouble in some place or another. But since you want to remove the two suffixes `.php` _and `.html`, you will have to perform the “check” which version actually exists, yourself using a combination of RewriteConds and -Rules, if you disable MultiViews.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I assumed I would have to turn off Muiltiviews after reading another article. I read something about GoDaddy needing them on and I wasn't sure why, but I am self-hosting the machine so I may have more flexibility there.